# Generating a Random string for a given length

Tags: javascript, random

I have some problems here.

a)I would like to set the 3-8 characters,but it only show 3 characters.

b)I would like to have three output with different display time.Do I only nid to create different Id?

Anyone can help? What's wrong with this code? Thanks.

Javascript

```
        function randomString(Length)
        {
        if(Length < 3) Length = 3;
        if(Length > 8) Length = 8;
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            for( var i=0; i < Length; i++ )
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            return text;
        }

        function ChangingRandomString(Length)
        {
            setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("random").style.fontSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 10)+"px",
                document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomString(Length);
            },2000);
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ChangingRandomString`, what length did you pass? How does your HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, create some different ids, and make the element another parameter of `ChangingRandomString` so that you can call it three times.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function randomString(length) {
  if (length < 3) length = 3;
  if (length > 8) length = 8;
  var text = '';
  var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)];
  }
  return text;
}

function ChangingRandomString(length) {
  setInterval(() => {
    let el = document.getElementById('random');
    el.style.fontSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 10) + 'px';
    el.innerHTML = randomString(length);
  }, 2000);
}

ChangingRandomString(length);
```

```html
<div id="random"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomString(length){
    if(length<5) length =5;
  if(length>8) length =8;
            var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(let i=0;i<=length;i++){
            text +=possible[Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length)]
      }
      return text
}

function string(length){
    setInterval(() => {
            console.log(randomString(length));
        },2000);
}

string(5);
```